# Ruby Instance Methods and Variables

Tags: ruby, class, variables, methods, instance

There is something that i don't understand about ruby **class instance variable or methods****. 
So i have this code that keeps on giving me this error and i cant understand

Looks ruby thinks that i am trying to call for  Float.in_celsius but I want to make this call within my class instance.

```
#-----------------------------------
def ftoc(fr)
fr = fr.to_f
if (fr == 32)
    c = 0
elsif (fr == 212)
    c = 100
else 
    c = (fr-32.0)*(5.0/9.0)
end

return c
end

def ctof (cl)
cl = cl.to_f
f = (cl*(9.0/5.0))+32.0
return f
end
#-----------------------------------

class Temperature
attr_accessor :in_celsius, :in_fahrenheit 

#class metods 
def self.from_celsius(cel)
    puts "from celsious\n"
    puts "cel: #{cel}\n"
    @in_fahrenheit = cel
    @in_celsius = ctof(cel)
    puts "==============================\n"
    return @in_celsius
end

def self.in_celsius
    @in_celsius
end


end


puts "==============================\n"
puts Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_celsius
puts Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_fahrenheit
```

and Error is 
`test.rb:54: in  '<main>' : undefined method 'in_celsius' for 122.0:float (noMethod Error)
    enter code here`

Comment: You probably want to use a module for this sort of thing - just my 2c

Comment: Grag, you can simplify `ftoc(fr)` to `def ftoc(fr) (fr-32.0)*(5.0/9.0) end`.  You don't need to convert `fr` to a float, because `fr-32.0` will do that, and you don't need `return` because Ruby returns the last calculation performed.  Same for `ctof()`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland OP is having confusion about the class instance variables and instance variables of class instances.. That needs to be fixed first.

Comment: WEll yes .. my main issue is with Class instance variables here :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how classes work in Ruby. Right now all of your variables and methods are defined at *class level*. That means that everything you do in the methods is acting directly on the class itself. Instead, you should create *instances* of `Temperature`.

```
class Temperature
  # special method called when creating a new instance
  def initialize celsius
    @in_celsius = celsius
    @in_fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5.0 + 32
  end

  def self.from_celsius celsius
    new celsius # built in method to create an instance, passes argument to initialize
  end

  # we defined initialize using celsius, so here we must convert
  def self.from_fahrenheit fahrenheit
    new((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9.0)
  end

  private_class_method :new # people must use from_celsius or from_fahrenheit

  # make instance variables readable outside the class
  attr_accessor :in_celsius, :in_fahrenheit
end

Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_celsius
```

This code isn't perfect (`from_fahrenheit` does a redundant conversion) but it should give you the idea of how to redesign your class.

Comment: new((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9.0)  Did the trick. 
My code different allot but this solved my problem ... 
Great thanks !

Answer (score 0):

from_celsius is returning a float which doesn't have an in_celsius method. You need it to return an instance of Temperature which would have that method.

Got to say your intent is a tad confusing, unless you have some other uses for the class Temperature, so it's  bit hard to say which way you should go.

Comment: I think `return @in_celsius` useless, so it can be removed. As OP has the line `attr_accessor :in_celsius, :in_fahrenheit`, `def self.in_celsius..` doesn't make sense although.

Comment: with the use of class level methods returning an instance of Temperature would not work for him either

Comment: @Arup Rakshit 
Why do you say that 
    `attr_accessor :in_celsius, :in_fahrenheit, def self.in_celsius`
does not make sense ?

Comment: @Arup Rakshit 
I am very new to ruby and syntax is still very confusing for me here.
I was using  `attr_accessor :in_celsius` as it is required to make `Temperature.in_celsius ` call.  So what i am trying to achieve is to chain my requests, as you can see in `puts Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_celsius`

Comment: @user3290330, I Would have expected Temperature to be a value and unit and any conversion to change both value and unit.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the code `puts Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_celsius` in details:

1. Call to singleton method `::from_celsius` of `Temperature` class. That is ok (with some stranges), and t returns as instance of `Float` class because of result of `#ctof` method.
2. Call to instance method `#in_celsius` of object, which is returned from the previous method. Since it was the `Float`, the [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) interpreter searches for its instance method `#in_celsius`, hasn't find it out, and throws the `NoMethodError` exception.

**How to fix.**

Since you treat `::from_celsius` as a constructor of `Temperature` class, I believe, that you shell to pass the floating value into the new method, and return created object. You will have class code as follows:

```
def initialize( value )
   @in_fahrenheit = cel
   @in_celsius = ctof(cel)
end

def self.from_celsius(cel)
   puts "from celsious\n"
   puts "cel: #{cel}\n"
   temp = Temperature.new( cel )
   puts "==============================\n"
   return temp
end
```

Comment: Hmm .. that looks like something i read about Ruby classes ... 
I think i get an idea  Will try it  later today ...

Comment: Thank you ... for response ... I yet can not add point for your answer as i have no reputation in here yet.