# Classes and class return variables

Tags: ruby, class, return-value

I need a class to return another class, but fail to do so. Can you explain me why that happens? Here I am not including `Temperature` class as I think that is irrelevant.

```
class Celsius
  attr_accessor :temp
  def initialize(cel)
    return Temperature.new({:c =>cel})
  end
end

class Fahrenheit
  def initialize ( far )
    Temperature.new({:f => far})
  end
end
```

I want to call `Fahrenheit` class to return a `Temperature` class

```
puts Fahrenheit.new(0) #=> returns  Fahrenheit class instead of Temperature
```

In `Celsius`, I tried to use `return`, but it did not help.

Comment: Sidenote: why don't you make `Fahrenheit::Temperature`?

Comment: It looks like you're still confused after [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663548/ruby-instance-methods-and-variables/21667363) question. You aren't trying to return *classes* here, you're trying to return *instances* of another class. There is a big difference.

Comment: @Max You are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `initialize` is not used in any way by `new`, so returning something from `initialize` serves no purpose. The only way to make `Foo.new` return something other than a `Foo` would be to override `new` directly, but that's usually not a good idea as it would be very confusing to the reader of your code.

If you have no intention of creating instances of your Celsius and Fahrenheit classes, they probably shouldn't be classes in the first place. In this case it would seem most sensible to me if your `Temperature` class had class methods `celsius` and `fahrenheit`.

Comment: Well problem is that do need to create class Celsius & Fahrenheit . Trying to do some practice exercises.  :/ feel  bothered that something simple like this stops me from proceeding :/

Comment: You got me to the right direction ! 
This is how i wrote it >
``

Comment: You got me to the right direction ! 
This is how i wrote it >

    `class Celsius
        def.self.new(cel)
            return Temperature.new({:c => cel})
        end
    end`

Answer (score 2):

> Fahrenheit class instead of Temperature

This is correct because `::new` consctuctor returns a newly created instance of the class, which was specified `Temperature`. But `#initialize` is really not a class constructor, it is just an initialization callback method.

You can use the following scheme:

```
far = Fahrenheit.new( 0 )
far.to_c # => Celsius
```

and the `Fahrenheit` class to the scheme:

```
class Fahrenheit
   def initialize( far )
      @temp = far
   end

   def to_c
      Celsius.new @temp
   end
end
```

In order to detect whether the class belongs to a `Temperature` class, just inherit `Fahrenheit` from it, and check as follows:

```
class Fahrenheit < Temperature
end

far = Fahrenheit.new
far.is_a?( Temperature )
# => true
```

Comment: @sawa what is AYBABTU? =)

Comment: It is easy to search on the internet. If you cannot, try to find "all your base are belong to us".

Comment: @sawa ok, but what does it mean in this context?

Comment: Look at your original.

Comment: It is a great surprise that you cannot find point to `"is belonged"` in your own text.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show resulting code.
So simple, but still i had to ask :)

```
class Celsius
    def.self.new(cel)
        return Temperature.new({:c => cel})
    end
end
```